# 2006 Saturn Ion won't shift into drive but will in reverse

Tags: electrical, transmission, automatic-transmission, saturn

Couple of days ago my 2006 Saturn Ion transmission stopped working. I can put the car into drive but when I hit the gas it just revs up and doesn't actually go anywhere - it will roll though like it's in neutral when it's in drive.

That being said when I put it in reverse it works just fine, which leads me to believe it's not a transmission issue. I haven't taken it to a mechanic yet because it was suggested to me that this could be a electrical issue so when I put it in drive, it's not communicating with the transmission to be in drive.

I did speak to a mechanic on the phone and he said that because reverse will work but drive won't, leads him to believe it's not the transmission at all, but he's not 100% sure.

What do you think, could it be the transmission,  an electrical issue or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its an issue with the transmission. If it was an electrical issue you get a warning light in the cluster. I have encountered a similar case in Mercedes E class which had a similar issue, but the other way around. Reverse won't work. We overhauled the entire transmission and the issue got fixed.

Comment: Yeah turns out it was the transmission, ended up buying a new vehicle. Wasn't worth pouring the money into this car, its a GM......Thanks for your answer, much appreciated.